# Using user input for javascript function (for loop)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, input, user-input

I have a basic js function that connects to my html file. I want the user to input a number and then the function will count up to that number. As it counts it will display a circle with each number. So, input 3 and you'll see three circles counting 1, 2, 3 horizontally on the page.

[image]

When I call the function and hard code an input like:

```
display(9)
```

it works fine.
I console log my user input, I console log as I loop through and it's counting just fine, but for some reason,

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const main = document.querySelector("main");


let number = "";

function display(num) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log("in the loop " + i);
    number += `<div>${i}</div>`;
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let input = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
  console.log(input);
  display(input);
});

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = number;
```

```html
<h1 class="h1">Test Form</h1>

<input class="input" id="input" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Enter" />

<p class="display" id="display"></p>
```

it won't display anything using user input.

My code is below. Thoughts? And thank you for the help!

Comment: `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = number;` this line of code needs to be after for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You just add the following statements to the end of `display` function to make it work.

```
  let displayDiv=document.getElementByI("display");
  displayDiv.innerHTML=number;
```